# How to fix Page not found in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have created a template for menu showing, but when I run my server, I got an error that my page is not found. Any suggestions?

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in WAD_Group_Project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='index']
restaurant/ [name='index']
restaurant/ about/ [name='about']
restaurant/ restaurant/menu/<slug:menu_name_slug>/ [name='show_menu']
restaurant/ restricted/ [name='restricted']
admin/
accounts/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, restaurant/menu/, didn't match any of these.
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from restaurant import views
app_name = 'restaurant'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name = 'about'),
    path('menu/<slug:menu_name_slug>/', views.show_menu, name='show_menu'),
    path('restricted/', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
]
```

views.py

```
def show_menu(request, menu_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    
    try:
        menu = Menu.objects.get(slug=menu_name_slug)
        menuItems = MenuItem.objects.filter(menu=menu)
        context_dict['menuItems'] = menuItems
    except Menu.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['menuItems'] = None

    return render(request, 'menu.html', context=context_dict)
```

Comment: You need to pass a slug also.

Comment: I need to pass it from views.py?

Comment: the route `show_menu` is not properly configure. On traceback its defined as "restaurant/ restaurant/menu/<slug:menu_name_slug>/" but on the urls file its defined as "menu/<slug:menu_name_slug>/". can you post main urls.py file?

Comment: show code of that template

Comment: Try to pass it in the url, then you can in the place which request this view.